# iOS duplicate/zombie view controller being referenced

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uikit

I have a `MainWindow` class that is built from a nib and set up as follows:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
    MainViewController *mainView = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController"
                                                                        bundle:nil];
    if(!mainView)
    {
        return;
    }
    naviController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainView];
    [naviController setToolbarHidden:YES];
    [[naviController navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [[naviController toolbar] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.window setRootViewController:naviController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

This works and correctly displays the `MainViewController`, but when I try to scroll down in the `MainViewController`'s table view it throws an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. Apparently UIKit is referring to a second `MainViewController` that was built in `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];` I can't figure out why it is referencing that over the one I passed into `initWithRootViewController:mainView`.

Here are the two `MainViewControllers`. The first one I initialize, the second is created in `makeKeyAndVisible`.

[image]

Here is the second `MainViewController` being called as a zombie.

[image]

Any ideas on why this is happening?

As requested:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MainViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainViewCell"];
    int i = [indexPath row];
    NSLog(@"%d\n",i);
    if (cell == nil) {
        // Create a temporary UIViewController to instantiate the custom cell.
        UIViewController *temporaryController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewCell" bundle:nil];
        // Grab a pointer to the custom cell.
        cell = (MainViewCell *)temporaryController.view;
        // Release the temporary UIViewController.
        [temporaryController release];
    }
    [[cell icon] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[[moduleXMLList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"thumbnail"]]];
    [[cell title] setText:[[moduleXMLList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"title"]];
    [[cell description] setText:[[moduleXMLList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"description"]];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning all targets?

Comment: Now I have. It had the same result.

Comment: Other than that, what usually solves these kinds of problems is reset content and settings in the simulator, restart Xcode, and of necessary reboot your computer

Comment: Wow that looks odd. Is it perhaps similar to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739405/weird-sigabrt-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-when-using-uialertview ? No proper solution annoyingly but maybe it helps?

Comment: Still no luck. It may also be worth mentioning that I am loading custom `UITableViewCells` as described at http://www.bdunagan.com/2009/06/28/custom-uitableviewcell-from-a-xib-in-interface-builder/  and while a handful load initially, it throws the exception when I try to scroll down to a new cell. That being said, it isn't thrown from any of my methods.

Comment: It still might be your methods causing it.  Try showing your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using File's Owner as a MainViewController while having a second UIViewController under Objects. This is wrong, and so once I got rid of the Object and just used File's Owner it worked like a charm.